# How can you smooth scrubbing a video while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm using scrollmagic and gsap on my page to scroll through a video, kinda like Apple on this page here: https://www.apple.com//homepod/

Not sure if they use a video as well but it's the same effect I'm trying to achieve.

Anyway, my script works great on Macbook/Safari but Macbook/Chrome stutters a little bit, on PC its even worse with a regular mouse instead of the trackpad.

Is there any way to achieve a smooth scrolling experience, like somehow make the video "catch up" if someone scrolls in "larger" steps with a mouse.

Below you can find the code I have so far:

```js
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const long = document.getElementById('long');
let scrollpos = 0;
let lastpos;
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
const scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: long,
  triggerHook: "onEnter"
});
const startScrollAnimation = () => {
  scene
    .addTo(controller)
    .duration(long.clientHeight)
    .on("progress", (e) => {
      scrollpos = e.progress;
    });

  setInterval(() => {
    if (lastpos === scrollpos) return;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      video.currentTime = video.duration * scrollpos;
      video.pause();
      lastpos = scrollpos;
    });
  }, 50);
};

const preloadVideo = (v, callback) => {
  const ready = () => {
    v.removeEventListener('canplaythrough', ready);

    video.pause();
    var i = setInterval(function() {
      if (v.readyState > 3) {
        clearInterval(i);
        video.currentTime = 0;
        callback();
      }
    }, 50);
  };
  v.addEventListener('canplaythrough', ready, false);
  v.play();
};

preloadVideo(video, startScrollAnimation);

startScrollAnimation();
```

```css
#video {
  position: fixed;
}

#long {
  height: 20000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>

<video id="video" src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
</video>

<div id="long"></div>
```

Comment: Why use ScrollMagic? https://codepen.io/ollieRogers/pen/lfeLc/

Comment: The Apple site uses image sprites, not a video BTW.

Comment: I‘m using scrollmagic because I want the video to be pinned while scrolling - the codepen you linked also doesn‘t seem to work on mobile (iOS). And thanks for the info Zach!

Comment: The CodePen is a mvp, you could modify it to work on mobile

Comment: I will check it out, thank you!

Comment: I got this to work a while back. Make sure the video has a keyframe interval of 1-3 to ensure smooth scrolling, especially when scrolling up.